# Does anyone know why Yahoo Finance returns null for bid?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I use the following link to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance.

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22IBM%22)

```
{
   "query":{
      "count":1,
      "created":"2016-12-17T10:53:58Z",
      "lang":"en-GB",
      "diagnostics":{+}, // collapsed
      "results":{
         "quote":{
            "symbol":"IBM",
            "Ask":null, <---- NULL
            "AverageDailyVolume":"3605490",
            "Bid":null, <---- NULL
            "AskRealtime":null,
            "BidRealtime":null,
            "BookValue":"17.89",
            "Change_PercentChange":"-1.89 - -1.12%",
            "Change":"-1.89",
            "Commission":null,
            "Currency":"USD",
            "ChangeRealtime":null,
            "AfterHoursChangeRealtime":null,
            "DividendShare":"5.60",
            "LastTradeDate":"12/16/2016",
            "TradeDate":null,
            "EarningsShare":"12.27",
            "ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid":null,
            "EPSEstimateCurrentYear":"13.50",
            "EPSEstimateNextYear":"13.90",
            "EPSEstimateNextQuarter":"2.52",
            "DaysLow":"166.13",
            "DaysHigh":"169.11",
            "YearLow":"116.90",
            "YearHigh":"169.95",
            "HoldingsGainPercent":null,
            "AnnualizedGain":null,
            "HoldingsGain":null,
            "HoldingsGainPercentRealtime":null,
            "HoldingsGainRealtime":null,
            "MoreInfo":null,
            "OrderBookRealtime":null,
            "MarketCapitalization":"157.97B",
            "MarketCapRealtime":null,
            "EBITDA":"17.54B",
            "ChangeFromYearLow":"49.23",
            "PercentChangeFromYearLow":"+42.11%",
            "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime":null,
            "ChangePercentRealtime":null,
            "ChangeFromYearHigh":"-3.82",
            "PercebtChangeFromYearHigh":"-2.25%",
            "LastTradeWithTime":"1:09pm - <b>166.13</b>",
            "LastTradePriceOnly":"166.13",
            "HighLimit":null,
            "LowLimit":null,
            "DaysRange":"166.13 - 169.11",
            "DaysRangeRealtime":null,
            "FiftydayMovingAverage":"160.02",
            "TwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"157.25",
            "ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"8.88",
            "PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage":"+5.65%",
            "ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage":"6.11",
            "PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage":"+3.82%",
            "Name":"International Business Machines",
            "Notes":null,
            "Open":"168.97",
            "PreviousClose":"168.02",
            "PricePaid":null,
            "ChangeinPercent":"-1.12%",
            "PriceSales":"1.99",
            "PriceBook":"9.39",
            "ExDividendDate":"11/8/2016",
            "PERatio":"13.54",
            "DividendPayDate":"12/10/2016",
            "PERatioRealtime":null,
            "PEGRatio":"4.37",
            "PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear":"12.31",
            "PriceEPSEstimateNextYear":"11.95",
            "Symbol":"IBM",
            "SharesOwned":null,
            "ShortRatio":"6.77",
            "LastTradeTime":"1:09pm",
            "TickerTrend":null,
            "OneyrTargetPrice":"156.62",
            "Volume":"3524102",
            "HoldingsValue":null,
            "HoldingsValueRealtime":null,
            "YearRange":"116.90 - 169.95",
            "DaysValueChange":null,
            "DaysValueChangeRealtime":null,
            "StockExchange":"NYQ",
            "DividendYield":"3.36",
            "PercentChange":"-1.12%"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Does anyone know why the fields for Ask and Bid are null? I've only tested a few companies, but it seems to be with IBM only for the time being?

Comment: twitter seems to be faulty also

Comment: I'm facing the very same issue here. Are you querying the API during open market time?

Comment: For me, it didn't matter when i used the api, id always run into the issue. I ended up using this library: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yahoofinance-api/YahooFinanceAPI/3.5.0.  Hope this helps.